# Okta SP initiated Single Logout(SLO) configuration with Spring Security WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, okta, single-logout

I am using SAML authentication for my Spring boot application with Okta as IdP. The Single Signon(SSO) configuration is done and working as expected. But I am stuck with configuring Single Logout(SLO). I want to use SP initiated Logout. Please assist me to proceed further.

Mentioned below is the configure method that I created by extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/saml*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .apply(saml())
                .serviceProvider()
                    .keyStore()
                        .storeFilePath(this.keyStoreFilePath)
                        .password(this.password)
                        .keyname(this.keyAlias)
                        .keyPassword(this.password)
                        .and()
                    .protocol("https")
                    .hostname(String.format("%s:%s", "localhost", this.port))
                    .basePath("/")
                    .and()
                .identityProvider()
                .metadataFilePath(this.metadataUrl);
    }
```

Comment: Did you check that the IdP metadata provided has a SingleLogout endpoint defined?
And you might need to add logout() to the config? Debugging the setup done by the saml configurer might help.

Comment: @Vamsi were you able to figure out this?

Comment: No luck yet @Jai